# React js not navigating to pages using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I type anything in my http://localhost:3000/anything it will do the same as if I type home or / or login, nothing. The page will be blank.

My social.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from '../../containers/Pages/Home/Home';
import Login from '../../containers/Pages/Login/Login';

class Social extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Social;
```

app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from './Layout/Layout'
import Social from './containers/Pages/Social';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
        <Layout>
            <Social />
        </Layout>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any ideas what is wrong?
Thanks.

----- Edit, I notice when I remove `<Layout> ... </Layout>` from app.js it works.

my Layout.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Toolbar from '../components/Navigation/Toolbar/Toolbar';

class Layout extends Component {
    
    render() {
        return (
        <>
            <Toolbar />
        </>
        );
    }
}

export default Layout;
```

and Toolbar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import classes from './Toolbar.module.css';

class toolbar extends Component {
    
    render() {
        return(
        <>
            <header className={classes.Toolbar}>
                toolbar
            </header>
        </>
        );
    }
    
}

export default toolbar;
```

Comment: Use `exact` property in the routes. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Looks everything correct, I tested your code added my own components in place of Home and Login. May be you have console error while rendering home or any component. Can you check.

Comment: @BlackMath I'd like to open the `/home` and `/login`. but all pages are blank

Comment: @Pavan the only error I got is `src\containers\Pages\Home\Home.js
  Line 2:8:   'firebase' is defined but never used`

Comment: I also paste my index.js code...

Comment: have you seen your console yet? any error?

Comment: @HasanTareque I notice when I place <Layout><Social /></Layout> my app crashes. I don't know why.

Comment: please show us the layout code

Comment: @HasanTareque I edit my question with it in the end.

Comment: You are not rendering `Social` component which has all the routes and that's why routes don't get defined and it renders nothing. To make it work: you need to use `this.props.children`

Answer (score 1):

I think you missing the wrapping element around **Toolbar** component

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
    import Toolbar from '../components/Navigation/Toolbar/Toolbar';
    
    class Layout extends Component {
        
        render() {
            return (
           <div>
                <Toolbar />
            <div>
            );
        }
    }

export default Layout;
```

same with the Toolbar. should be as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import classes from './Toolbar.module.css';

class Toolbar extends Component {
    
    render() {
        return(
        <div>
            <header className={classes.Toolbar}>
                toolbar
            </header>
        </div>
        );
    }
    
}

export default Toolbar;
```

Comment: Same error as before, /home or /login not show. They only will show the content if I remove <Layout> from app.js ;/

Comment: try with these changes please

Comment: Have you found any luck?

Comment: I did the changes but nothing ;/

Comment: No bro, strange. But I'll remove the `<Layout><Social /></Layout>` to <Social /> and do something different... Thanks a lot for your help.